# How to make graph from perf4j log file?

Tags: java, log4j, perf4j

I have used perf4j to calculate the performance of the process. Now I want to make the graph for that file. Is it possible to make it without using Google API or any other method that can be used?

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of options:

1. When you use the org.perf4j.LogParser to parse your log, you can use the "--format csv" option to generate CSV output, open this up in Excel, then create a graph in Excel.
2. As the other poster said, I'm not sure why you're against using the Google Chart API, but if you are dead set against using it, note that the JFreeChart guys provide an implementation of the Google Chart APIs called Eastwood Charts: http://www.jfree.org/eastwood/. You could just set up an eastwood server and then proxy (or just set up in a hosts file) chart.apis.google . com to your eastwood server. Alternatively, if you look at the org.perf4j.LogParser class, you can override the newMeanTimeChartGenerator and newTpsChartGenerator methods to call the GoogleChartGenerator constructor that takes the base URL.
3. You can always create another implementation of the StatisticsChartGenerator interface and use this instead. Obviously this is the most involved option.

Answer (score 3):

Can you explain a bit more as to why you want to avoid Google Charting APIs (I ask since I am intrigued as to why someone would not want to do something that is very simple, elegant and FREE)?

Also there is a [GraphingServlet](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/devguide.html) section "Exposing Performance Graphs in a Web Application" which I think internally does the same thing.

If you still want you can take the graph data (in raw csv format) and write some helper classes to create charts using libraries like jfreechart (rich client)

Answer (score 0):

follow the following steps;

1. Go to the location where your perf4j log file exits and open command prompt there.
2. Hit the following command in cmd, make sure you have java(jdk) path set as environment variable and perf4j jar on this location:

java -jar perf4j-0.9.16.jar --graph perfGraphs.html perfLogFile.log

this will generate perfGraphs.html file in this location, which consists of graphs.